# Swift - Why String doesn't conform to RawRepresentable?

Tags: swift, rawrepresentable

I'm learning Swift and cannot realize why this code is correct:

```swift
enum Test1: String {
    case value
}

let test1 = Test1.value.rawValue
```

but this one is incorrect and shows me errors

```swift
struct MyStruct {
}

extension MyStruct: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: MyStruct, rhs: MyStruct) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

enum Test2: MyStruct {
    case value
}
```

I browsed thru `Swift.String` sources and didn't find `rawValue` declaration. How does it work in Swift? Is `String` a built-in type that "automatically" conforms to `RawRepresentable`, but all other types have to explicitly declare its conformance?

Comment: What are the errors?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that `Test.value` has type `Test1`, not `String`.

There is special treatment (implicit conformance to `RawRepresentable`), but it applies to string-valued enums, not `String` itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Raw values can be strings, characters, or any of the integer or
> floating-point number types. Each raw value must be unique within its
> enumeration declaration.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html

---

But that's only for using the colon-based shortcut syntax. It's no problem to manually conform.

```swift
enum Test2 {
  case value
}

extension Test2: RawRepresentable {
  init?(rawValue: MyStruct) {
    self = .value
  }
  
  var rawValue: MyStruct { .init() }
}
```